# Using LINQ Query DataTable using partial column names

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable with a variable number of columns.
I want to create a LINQ query that returns the data from the columns that start with a 'B_'.
I have a query that returns the columns names that start with 'B_'.  It is below:

```
var arrayNames = (from DataColumn x in stationTable.Columns
                          where x.ColumnName.Contains("B_")
                          select x.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

Now that I have the column names how to I create a query using this array to return the data in the columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `DataView` that hides the columns *not* in your list - that way you get to keep any type information:

```
var arrayNames = (from DataColumn x in stationTable.Columns
                          where !x.ColumnName.Contains("B_")  // note the reversal
                          select x.ColumnName).ToArray();

DataView dv = new DataView(stationTable);

foreach (string colName in arrayNames)    
    dv.Table.Columns[colName].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to approach this.

If you don't care about grouping the items by column type, this query accomplishes that:

```
var query = from DataColumn col in stationTable.Columns
            from DataRow row in stationTable.Rows
            where col.ColumnName.StartsWith("B_")
            select row[col.ColumnName];
```

However, to maintain the grouping, you could use a lookup as follows:

```
var query = (from DataColumn col in stationTable.Columns
            from DataRow row in stationTable.Rows
            where col.ColumnName.StartsWith("B_")
            select new { Row = row[col.ColumnName], col.ColumnName })
            .ToLookup(o => o.ColumnName, o => o.Row);

foreach (var group in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ColumnName: {0}", group.Key);
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

The downside of either approach is you're ending up with an `object`. Retaining the results in a strongly typed manner would require some extra work given the dynamic nature of the question.